# Usar o ResultSet sem saber o tipo da coluna

Tags: java, jdbc

Preciso usar um ResultSet que retornou os dados de uma consulta no Banco de Dados. Estou fazendo uma classe bem genérica, ela vai poder ser usada em qualquer tabela, por isso eu não sei o tipo de dados que ele ta retornando.

Por exemplo, a coluna Nome vai retornar uma String. Sabendo disso eu faria: resultSet.getString(1).

Como fazer isso sem saber o tipo de dado da coluna?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Recuperando um objeto genericamente

Uma opção seria usar o método [`ResultSet.getObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29). A documentação do método diz que o tipo do objeto retornado será o [padrão da especificação JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) para o tipo correspondente do banco de dados.

Assim, bastaria usar o operador `instanceof` para testar o tipo retornado ou o método [`isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) da classe. Por exemplo:

```java
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
Object o = rs.getObject(1);

if (Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) 
    System.out.println("true"); //verdadeiro

if (o instanceof Integer)
    System.out.println("true"); //verdadeiro
```

## Obtendo informações detalhadas sobre os resultados

Uma segunda opção consiste em recuperar o [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) resultante da consulta. É uma forma mais complexa, mas permite obter informações precisas sobre as colunas.

Veja um exemplo de como obter as colunas e os tipos:

```java
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

//quantidade de colunas
int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

int type = rsmd.getColumnType(1);
if (type == Types.VARCHAR || type == Types.CHAR) {
    //executa alguma ação
}
```

Comment: o o.getObject(1), o número 1 seria o que? Existe a forma de pegar passando o nome da coluna?

Comment: @AndréNascimento O número aí seria a posição da coluna no retorno da consulta. Existe a versão com o nome do campo. Clique no primeiro link da resposta e consulte o Javadoc para mais detalhes.